# execute batchfile with relative path in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to manage a few batchfiles with python and execute those by adding a gui with buttons later.
The whole thing should only run on windows machines. I need to make it portable so it can run from any folder.

My current code looks like this

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\app\test.bat'])
```

I tried to work with pathlib but I could not integrate the variable (current_path) to the subprocess:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import pathlib

current_path = pathlib.Path().resolve()

#print(current_path)
p = Popen("test.bat", cwd=r current_path)
```

I know this might be a noob question but I am thankful for any advice!
I also searched the forum and the web but could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with using the pathlib module to get the current working directory, which is the folder where your Python script is located. By using pathlib, you can make your script more portable, meaning that it will work regardless of where it is located on the computer.

The issue with your current implementation is a small mistake in the Popen call. In the second line of your code, you have a syntax error with the cwd parameter. Instead of "r current_path", you should remove the "r" and put the current_path variable directly after "cwd=".

To fix this, you can change the code to this:

```
import subprocess
import pathlib

current_path = pathlib.Path().resolve()

p = subprocess.Popen("test.bat", cwd=current_path)
```

Alternatively, you can also use the os module to change the working directory to the location of your batch file and then call it with subprocess.call(). This method allows you to call the batch file without having to specify its full path.

Here's an example:

```
import os
import subprocess
import pathlib

current_path = pathlib.Path().resolve()

# change the current working directory to the folder where the batch file is located
os.chdir(current_path)

# call the batch file
subprocess.call('test.bat')
```

Both versions of the code should work on Windows machines, regardless of where the script and batch file are located. You can later add a GUI with buttons to call these functions as needed.